# how can I use python to build dynamic web sites?

Tags: python

I'm PHP/MySQL developper 
I studied python well as a desktop programming two years ago but I don't use it on the web 
**how can I use python to build *dynamic web sites* and *easily uploads these sites to any hosting providers***

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: I heard that these frameworks required a special hosting provider

Comment: So does PHP. PHP is just more common.

Comment: Unfortunately, My new work requires python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many web frameworks such as Django & web2py , you should check them out

Comment: I heard that these frameworks required a special hosting provider

Comment: well here are some web hosts for django http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Comment: @web lover: No they don't require a "special" hosting provider. However, you can't run them on the hosting providers that are so special that they only allow CGI, while you can do that with PHP solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You cant' upload python files and use it on any webhosting.
You can use them if the host allows it.
Some frameworks are Django or Pylons.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Django project](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [web2py](http://web2py.com/) and also [web frameworks for python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)